# Keeping format of a pdb file with conditionals

Tags: awk, protein-database

I'm new in awk, and I'm trying to modify column 3 (with numeration about NR) if column 1 has the word HETATM.

My input file is:

```
HETATM   25  O   UNL     1      86.047  83.059 103.165  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   26  N   UNL     1      87.071  82.457 102.433  1.00  0.00           N
HETATM   27  C   UNL     1      91.764  77.729  97.523  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   28  O   UNL     1      92.740  78.174  98.137  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   29  H   UNL     1      90.477  80.552  97.677  1.00  0.00           H
CONECT    1    2
CONECT    2    1    3
CONECT    3    2    4    7
```

The output that I want, it's:

```
HETATM   25  O25   UNL     1      86.047  83.059 103.165  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   26  N26   UNL     1      87.071  82.457 102.433  1.00  0.00           N
HETATM   27  C27   UNL     1      91.764  77.729  97.523  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   28  O28   UNL     1      92.740  78.174  98.137  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   29  H29   UNL     1      90.477  80.552  97.677  1.00  0.00           H
CONECT    1    2
CONECT    2    1    3
CONECT    3    2    4    7
```

I'm using this command to maintain the format of the file but I could not. Can you help me please?

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t";}{if($1=="HETATM"){$3=$3NR};print $0}' file.pdb
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question contains 2 separate questions. Please fix that to only ask the top question here and post a separate question for the bottom question.

Comment: This is clearly the PDB format. Columns here have fixed width but don't need to be separated with whitespace.

Comment: Hi Marcin, yes you have right, I only paste the lines of the pdb file and I need to change a column with respect other. If only use awk '$1=="HETATM" {$3=$3NR} {print}' file , the format change. Do you have any idea what I must to do?

Comment: @ThéréHernandez by posting a script that has `FS=OFS="\t"` in it you're telling us that the fields are tab-separated, not fixed width. Please [edit] your question to explicitly state the layout of your file and don't assume we'll know what "a pdb file" means - it's all just fields and lines to most of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/^HETATM *\([^ ]*\) *[^ ]*/&\1/' file
HETATM   25  O25   UNL     1      86.047  83.059 103.165  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   26  N26   UNL     1      87.071  82.457 102.433  1.00  0.00           N
HETATM   27  C27   UNL     1      91.764  77.729  97.523  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   28  O28   UNL     1      92.740  78.174  98.137  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   29  H29   UNL     1      90.477  80.552  97.677  1.00  0.00           H
CONECT    1    2
CONECT    2    1    3
CONECT    3    2    4    7
```

---

Original answer:

Assuming your input really is tab-separated as you indicate in your script, you were very, very close:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1=="HETATM"{$3=$3 $2} 1' file
HETATM  25      O25     UNL     1       86.047  83.059  103.165 1.00    0.00    O
HETATM  26      N26     UNL     1       87.071  82.457  102.433 1.00    0.00    N
HETATM  27      C27     UNL     1       91.764  77.729  97.523  1.00    0.00    C
HETATM  28      O28     UNL     1       92.740  78.174  98.137  1.00    0.00    O
HETATM  29      H29     UNL     1       90.477  80.552  97.677  1.00    0.00    H
CONECT  1       2
CONECT  2       1       3
CONECT  3       2       4       7
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, but the result is the same like the input. If I change $3=$3NR, is the same result. Any idea? Why the line has $2, is like paste?

Comment: The expression `$3 $2` means that you concatenate the third and the second field. Normally, it will not be the same as `$3 NR`, except if the value of the second field happens to be equal to the line number, which is not the case for the provided example. In the opposite case, edit the data sample to reflect that the value of `$2` matches the line number `NR`.

Comment: ThéréHernandez from [@marcin's recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67710551/keeping-format-of-a-pdb-file-with-conditionals#comment119683234_67710551) the problem is you're trying to populate the 3rd tab-separated field when the first tab-separated field is `HETATM` but your input file isn't separated by tabs, it's fixed-width, and so every line only has 1 field, $1, and therefore `$1=="HETATM"`  could only be true if the line ONLY contained `HETATM` which never occurs in your input.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a solution that produces the output you asked for from blank-separated input without changing the number of blanks between fields.